# What does the `fontsize` represent in `grid` graphics?

Tags: r, graphics, grid

The `fontsize` is used to determine the size of text or points in R graphics. But what does it actually represent? For example,

```
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.points(default.units = "npc", 
                  gp = gpar(fontsize = 100))
```

[image]

Here, the point `fontsize` is 100. So, I have two questions:

1. What does the value mean, the radius, the diameter or the area of a point? Can I find any reference?
2. What is the unit of 100? In specific, does it mean 100 pointsize (1 fontsize = 1pt)? Otherwise, is it determined by device-specification? If so, 1 fontsize = ?pt.

Also, I have another question that, in language R, is there any handy functions to convert `pt` to pixel (`px`)? For example, we can convert a `pt` unit to a `mm` unit as in

```
convertUnit(unit(1, "pt"), "mm", valueOnly = TRUE)
```

So, is there any function to query the dimension of the screen and then do the transformation from `pt` to `px`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the symbols drawn by grid.points() depend on several factors, primarily `pch`, which determines the shape of the symbol, and `size`.  By default, the latter is `unit(1, "char")`, which means the size further depends on the current font size (`fontsize` and `cex`).

Deep in the graphics engine source code (https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/master/src/main/engine.c#L2110) are some constants that further modify the nominal symbol size based on the symbol shape.  For example, `pch=1` multiplies size by .375 to get the circle radius.

Yes, `fontsize=100` means 100pt.

The following code demonstrates the calculations by drawing a symbol and a rectangle with the same width:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport())
grid.points(.5, .5)
grid.rect(width=2*.375*unit(1, "char"))
grid.points(.5, .5, gp=gpar(fontsize=100))
grid.rect(width=2*.375*unit(100, "pt"))
```